# FFMpeg - How to apply a scene select filter on an area of the frames

Tags: ffmpeg

This is a follow up question to:

[Using FFMPEG: How to do a Scene Change Detection? with timecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode#38205105)

Using FFmpeg to do scene change detection, the filter `select=gt(scene,0.3)` can be used to select the frames whose scene detection score is greater then 0.3.

**Question:** In FFmpeg, is possible to extend the filter so that only a scene select is applied on a defined area of the video frames?  In other words, using an example, how can one do a scene change detection of only the right hand side of the video frames?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1440682

Comment: I tried it and it outputs the final video at the dimensions of the crop.  It's close, but I least your post points me in the right direction of using filter_complex and split.  If I come across the solution I'll post it here.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess to explain a bit more as to why it doesn't work, the area within (lets say) [ crop=750:60:110:80 ] has high activity so [ select=gt(scene,0.3) ] needs to exclude that area.  I'll investigate further how to use filter_complex ...

Comment: *I tried it and it outputs the final video at the dimensions of the crop.* --> no, it outputs full-sized frames.  Do you want the cropped area to be excluded from consideration i.e. consider the entire frame except a window?