# Keyframes FFMPEG

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Is there a FFMPEG command, where if we pass a video file, on every scene changes it should produce a keyframe for it. And Keyframe to my understanding is a series of files(image or video) files for an video, which can be used for playing on hover of the video. Kindly let know if we can do this?

Comment: Have you seen this post ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a FFMPEG command, where if we pass a video file, on every
>   scene changes it should produce a keyframe for it.

Well, It depends on what codec, and what you are calling a scene. x264 has the scenecut parameter for adjusting scene sensitivity. However, what x264 calls a scene, may not be the same thing you call a scene.

A Michael bay movies for example has a hard cut every 4 or 5 seconds. x264 may consider every "cut" a scene. Anything more clever than a cut, or a fade, ffmpeg will not handle.

> And Keyframe to my understanding is a series of files(image or video)
>   files for an video, which can be used for playing on hover of the
>   video. Kindly let know if we can do this?

No, not at all.

A key frame is a single frame, not a series of frames or files. It also has nothing to do with "hover". A keyframe is just an independent frame, meaning you can decode it independently  without first having to decode any frames that it may reference.

Video compression does not just encode every frame. It will encode a frame, then for the next frame, encode only the parts that changed. This is called a "predicted frame" and it is not decodable without decoding the referenced frame. A key frame is just a frame that does not reference any other frames.

Sometimes some players may make optimizations where it will preview keyframes on hover because keyframes are faster to decode than predicted frames. But this is 100% a player optimization and not all plays do it.

To me, thed sounds line an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks for the response, am doing something like this,  ffmpeg -i .\test.mp4 -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.5)',showinfo" -f md5 -vsync 0 -s 120x68 keyframe%05d.jpeg  And its giving me the output. Now its creating a separate files. Is there any way i can create a output file with UUID appended. Eg: keyframe_UUID in ffmpeg

Comment: New questions should get a new post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270208/guid-appended-for-ffmpeg-output-file-name/62290077#62290077. Kindly find the post