# GUID appended for FFMPEG output file name

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to append a GUID to the output file?

I am running:

```
ffmpeg -i .\Tst.mp4 -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.5)',showinfo" -vsync 0 -s 120x68 keyframe%05d.jpg
```

Which produces a series of files. I need to append a GUID to every file name.

Comment: The output file name should be appended with a UniqueId(UUID). Eg: keyframe%05d.jpg. Consider Keyframe is my fileNama, i wanted an Unique Identifiershould be appended with it

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible with `ffmpeg`. However, you can use the [MD5 muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1) on the existing JPG files to provide 128-bit psuedo-UUID:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i "$f" -f hash -f md5 -
```

Result:

```
MD5=aa8f01566a88feb762337de3cc81f36
```

Bash example:

```
for f in *.jpg; do hash="$(ffmpeg -v error -i "$f" -f hash -f md5 -)"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}_${hash:5}.jpg"; done
```

Result:

```
keyframe_00001_aa8f01566a88feb762337de3cc81f36.jpg
keyframe_00002_49cbb3ea81acfd57edda9955b3f8ed6.jpg
keyframe_00003_31711067199dafd28a6504ec4a22e05.jpg
```

Not a true UUID but fine if you just need a unique identifier.

Comment: I didnt understood. Can you kindly modify the command what is in Question and let me know one command where i can get required output