# Using FFMPEG: How to do a Scene Change Detection by audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a video that has many scenes, within each scene there are several video cuts with and single unique narator.
I'm trying to split the video to individual scenes based on narator. So far only found only a way using select/scene to get timestamps based on scene video changes.

[Using FFMPEG: How to do a Scene Change Detection? with timecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode)

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv  \
       -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo" \
       -f null \
       - 2> ffout
```

Is there an equivalent way to get the scene changes by examining changes in audio?